# OTRS 5 PostMaster Filter

Tags: spam, otrs

I need to know if the function PostMaster Filter Management in OTRS 5 can proccess email ONLY of certain specifics domains.

For example: I want to process ticket from *@example.com *@otrs.con etc. But no any other domain.

Any help will be apreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it can!

All you need is to configure a Postmaster Filter and define a Filter Condition using the "From" field from e-mail header. You could use a regex like this:

```
.*@example.com|.*@otrs.con
```

All other domains you be ignored by this filter. It's good to double check other filters you maybe have already defined.